gcloud CLI Cloud Run .NET Deployment with project references
I have a webservice that runs in Google Cloud Run.
To deploy it, I open CMD in my project dir and run the CLI command
gcloud run deploy myService --source=. --region="us-central1"

I need to add a project reference to another project in my .net solution.
This obviously breaks the publish as the dependencies are not uploaded. I can confirm this by the build error on GCP and checking the output of
gcloud meta list-files-for-upload

This feels like a very common use case but I can't find any resources with examples of how I should be deploying my web service.I obviously don't want to upload the entire solution each time as there are loads of other projects in the solution that are not required for the web service.

Have a look at Link and Article.

Thanks a lot for the additional info. Not quite the quick win I was hoping for but I appreciate the useful links

Please provide your project structure as follows: https://tree.nathanfriend.com/? Also what do you mean by don't want to upload the entire solution each time.
